# Suddenly cannot run *any* Python processes on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, conda

I can suddenly not run *any* python process on Ubuntu 18.04. This morning I was running tests and jumping in REPL just fine. Now any operation hangs forever, and I can't even exit with CTRL+C/D. Just trying to run the REPL, for example, looks like this:

```sh
(base) [meadow] python
Python 3.7.12 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Oct 26 2021, 06:08:53) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
^C
```

I've tried:

- Restarting
- Switching `conda` environments
- Cleaning `conda`
- Creating fresh `conda` environment
- Updating `conda`
- Updating `conda` packages

Pretty it's the root python that's goofed, but I've tried running a few different ways

- Running in terminal
- Running from bpython
- Running from pytest
- Running from VSCode

Comment: You might go look for `site.py` in `/usr/local/lib` or in your `.local` tree, and see if something was added in there.  That gets run on every invocation.

Comment: Try running a script instead of starting an interactive session.  `python myscript.py`

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. @tim, what would I be looking for exactly? @john yes it just hangs as well but this helped me narrow down the issue. The scripts I was running on all imported one of my custom classes - which was also in my `~/.startup.py`. Removing that, python starts up! However, this class is non-negotiable for our work, and it hasn't changed in months either. In addition, it works on other machines just fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok turns out it's hanging on matplotlib import `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`. I uninstalled with `pip` and now trying to reinstall, but it says I already have it installed... but when I got to import it can't find it.